# create a Share Account signature in c#

Tags: c#, sql, azure, azure-blob-storage

I would like to access a file located in azure file shares to copy it into blob storage. It works when I create Shared Access Signature by using the Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer by right-clicking on the file and going through the process and then hardcode generated value in the code. But I cannot generate this value using this C# code.

```
var sharedAccessFilePolicy = new SharedAccessFilePolicy()
{
    Permissions = SharedAccessFilePermissions.Read,
    SharedAccessStartTime = DateTime.Now,
    SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
};
```

This code also generates an SAS but it does not work anyways. any idea?
BTW I'm using Microsoft.Azure.Storage NuGet

[image]

> sv=2019-02-02, sr=f, sig=****, se=****, sp=r"
>
> st=2019-11-06T10****, se=2019-11-07T10**[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVn3i.png)**, sp=rl, sv=2018-03-28, sr=f,
>   sig=****

the first one is generated by the code and the second one is the one that is comming from Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer

Comment: Try it with `DateTime.UtcNow` and preferably set the start time a little behind in time to for example `AddMinutes(-15)` in case system clocks are a bit off.

Comment: @404 thanks that helped

Comment: Any update one this issue? Could you create sas with my code?

Comment: @GeorgeChen read the comment from 404. That worked remember that AddMinute(-[some value]) is important

Answer (score 0):

The below code I have test, it could generate the file sas token and copy the file to blob.

```
static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var accountName = "accountname";
            var accountKey = "your account key";
            var account = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);
            var fileClient = account.CreateCloudFileClient();
            var share = fileClient.GetShareReference("windows");
            CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();
            var file = rootDir.GetFileReference("test.json");

            var sasToken = file.GetSharedAccessSignature(new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File.SharedAccessFilePolicy()
            {
                Permissions = SharedAccessFilePermissions.Read | SharedAccessFilePermissions.Write,
                SharedAccessExpiryTime = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1))
            });

            var uri = file.StorageUri.PrimaryUri + sasToken;
            Uri fileuri = new Uri(uri);
            Console.WriteLine(uri);
            var blobclient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var  containerClient =blobclient.GetContainerReference("test");
            var blob=containerClient.GetBlockBlobReference("test.json");
            await blob.StartCopyAsync(fileuri);

        }
```

Hope this could help you, if you still have other problem please feel free to let me know.